# Combining functions in python

Tags: python, list, function, loops

I need to run a function as following:

```
def func1(a):
    l=a+1
    print (l)

def func2(a,b):
    l=a+1
    z.append(l)
    l=b+1
    z.append(l)
    print (l)

def func2(a,b,c):
    l=a+1
    z.append(l)
    l=b+1
    z.append(l)
    l=c+1
    z.append(l)
    print (l)
```

and so on. Can somebody show me an alternative where I can combine all these functions to one function where I can add as many values as I want `(a,b,c,d..)` and the output given will be `a+1,b+1,c+1,d+1...` in a list?

Comment: Where is `z` declared?

Comment: just pass a list (or `*args`) as argument?

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `l = [i+1 for i in (a,b,c)]; print(l)`

Comment: Some creative ways... https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/wbs1o/best_way_to_increment_of_1_in_python/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a function to take a variable number of parameters, and then use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to work on them in one statement like:

#### Code:

```
def increment_to_list(*args):
    return [a + 1 for a in args]
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(increment_to_list(1,2,3))
print(increment_to_list(4,5,6,7,8))
```

#### Results:

```
[2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
def f(*args):
    l = []
    for i in args:
        l.append(i+1)

    return l
```

Or, if you like list comprehensions like me, you could do:

```
def f(*args):
    return [val + 1 for val in args]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Hi friend! Anytime! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want variable number of arguments with list output:

```
def myFunc(*args):
    return [i+1 for i in args]
```

Now you can get your `z` from this function like this:

```
z = myFunc(1,2,3,4)
z
#[2, 3, 4, 5]
```